# Jmeter logs not informative enough

Tags: logging, jmeter

I am facing an issue in Jmeter logs, I run 10 tests together, they all have the same steps but with different parameters.
When I check Jmeter logs I see exceptions on steps, but it is not mentioned on which test, So how can I know which scenario is doing the problem?

```
2017-12-18 14:56:10,223 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, Short_tt_cid
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158) ~[groovy-all-2.4.12.jar:2.4.12]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
```

the step short_tt_cid is in all tests, and when I use to print ID it is not displayed in logs,
Moreover the problem is just when I run couple of tests together, So how can I know what is the problem? how can I make Jmeter tell me more info in logs, for example the test name. I called the step with {test_name} and it is not displayed in logs
the problem is if I run only one test all the tests passes

Comment: Test name you mean test plan name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add variable, even in Test plan level which will save Test plan file and use it when needed using function [TestPlanName](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__TestPlanName) function:

```
${__TestPlanName}
```

> The TestPlanName function returns the name of the current test plan (can be used in Including Plans to know the name of the calling test plan).

for group name use `ctx.getThreadGroup().getName()` for example:

```
${__BeanShell(ctx.getThreadGroup().getName())}
```

Add it to a variable in 1 `User Parameters` **for each** Thread Group and use the variable whenever you need

Comment: I need the thread group name, since test plan is some tests (thread groups)

Comment: for group name use `${__BeanShell(ctx.getThreadGroup().getName())} `

Comment: Where should I use it? how to use it? can you please provide step by step solution? , shell I put it in every test and in every step meaning 10K times? do you have any example of how to do it?

Comment: Add it to a variable in 1 `User Parameters` **for each** Thread Group and use the variable whenever you need

Answer (score 1):

This is not about JMeter, it is about your Groovy code. The cause is that you're trying to invoke `substring()` function on a not defined (or null) variable.

If you need this to be more informative - the implementation is totally up to you, one of possible options is putting your code in [try block](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_exception_handling.htm) like:

```
try {
    def myObj = null
    myObj.substring()
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    log.info('Problem in ' + ctx.getCurrentSampler().getName() + ' in ' + ctx.getThreadGroup().getName() + ' Thread Group')
    throw ex
}
```

[image: Groovy exception handling]

This way you will have at least the relevant [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and [Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) name in the *jmeter.log* file. In the above example `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance, check out JavaDoc for all available methods and fields and [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter

Comment: Dimitri the problem is what if you have 30 tests and all of them use step "my sampler" how would you know which of them failed. according to your pic there is one thread group , if you have 30 thread groups how would you know on which step of which thread group it failed